# Algolia instantsearch angular 5, TypeError: instantsearch is not a function at component

Tags: angular, angular5, algolia

I'm trying to implement algolia instant search into my Angular 5 application, and are using this tutorial: [Angular Full Text Search With Algolia Frontend](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-full-text-search-with-algolia-frontend-part-1/) And i have installed instantsearch.js

I get a error: **`ERROR TypeError: instantsearch is not a function at SearchUiComponent.ngOnInit`**

I've tried to add the following to import statement:

```
import * as instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js';
declare var instantsearch: any;
```

And

```
import * as instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js/es'
```

SearchUi.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import * as instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js'

export class SearchUiComponent implements OnInit {

search: any;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
const options = environment.algolia;

this.search = instantsearch(options);

// search box widget
this.search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#search-box',
    autofocus: false,
    placeholder: 'Search for actors',
    poweredBy: true
  })
);
this.search.start();
```

SearchUi.html

```
<div id="search-box">
 <!-- SearchBox widget will appear here -->
</div>
<div id="hits">
 <!-- Hits widget will appear here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing import to seems to resolve the issue:

```
import instantsearch from 'instantsearch.js/dist-es5-module/src/lib/main';
```